# capistrano deploy:check success but deploy fails

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano, cap

This is my first time with capistrano and everything seems to be ok, but unfortunately deploying fails.

after a cap deploy:check it returns:

```
You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed
```

So I assume everything is ok. Time to deploy! But it returned this:

```
command finished in 81ms
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/alternate/domains/testserveraz.eu/public_html/shared/cached-copy ]; 
then cd /home/alternate/domains/testserveraz.eu/public_html/shared/cached-copy && 
git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 
d5018b4b253e082bae9dd8b7566c7840f26fecaa && git clean -q -d -x -f; 
else git clone -q git@brive.lt:testserveraz.git 
/home/alternate/domains/testserveraz.eu/public_html/shared/cached-copy && 
cd /home/alternate/domains/testserveraz.eu/public_html/shared/cached-copy && 
git checkout -q -b deploy d5018b4b253e082bae9dd8b7566c7840f26fecaa; fi'" on testserveraz.eu
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's fixed now. I changed the username in deploy.rb.
Although Now I have an other issue, the files are deployed to /home/alternate/domains/testserveraz.eu/releases and my server expect the files in public_html. I tried to create a symlink but no luck.

Comment: Since you solved it, add an answer to this thread so you get credit for figuring it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to connect to the user 'git' with the wrong credentials. So I changed the username in deploy.rb so it will use the correct username and password to upload the files.